# How can you persist data (in a secure way) when using webassembly?

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

How can you persist data in the browser (js) when using webassembly written in go?

Is it possible to save **a lot** of data a local database like sqlite?

For instance if I have a chat application and I want to cache all the received messages - but in a secure way so that you have to be authorized to read the messages.

Comment: Depends on browser and users free disk space: https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/#:~:text=the%20main%20thread.-,It%20is%20limited%20to%20about%205MB%20and%20can%20contain%20only,not%20be%20used%20for%20storage.